# Splitting text in element into multiple elements based on keywords/delimiters

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

**my source xml**

```xml
<event>
    <description>Special Notice - 20190305</description>
    <note>[Subject]: This is the subject of the event
    [Purpose]: This is the purpose of the event
    [Evaluation]: This is an evaluation of the event
    [Strategy]: This is the strategy for the event</note>
</event>
<event>
    <description>Notice</description>
    <note>This is a notice</note>
</event>
```

**what the result should look like**

```
<instance>
  <title>
   <text>Purpose</text>
  </title>
  <data>This is the purpose of the event</data>
</instance>
<instance>
  <title>
    <text>Subject</text>
  </title>
  <data>This is the subject of the event</data>
</instance>
<instance>
  <title>
   <text>Purpose</text>
  </title>
  <data>This is the purpose of the event</data>
</instance>
<instance>
  <title>
   <text>Notice</text>
  </title>
  <data>This is a notice</data>
</instance>
etc.
```

I'm pretty new to xslt and was stuck on something during an exercise - I have an idea of what I want to do but I'm having issues figuring out where to start. I'm looking to split the text from the note elements containing Subject, Purpose, Evaluation and Strategy into separate notes for each instance. **There will be notes with other content, but my question here is specifically about these particular notes.**

Each note element in source xml should have the portion of the sentence enclosed in square brackets serving as the title in destination xml; and whatever is after the colon goes under the data element, as well. My challenge has been figuring out how to parse what's under the note element and pass each line properly. I thought of using a for-each with some sort of regex to grab whatever is enclosed in each square bracket, but not sure if that's possible? Perhaps tokenize? Then I thought of using substring-before and substring-after to pass to the title and data elements, respectively.

EDIT: Just adding some more background, due to Daniel's suggestion to use analyze-string. As mentioned in bold above, there are some event elements that won't need to be split. I added an example of that to my source and destination xml. For these description and note should go to text and data, respectively.

As I mentioned in my reply to Daniel, my thinking is that value-of can just be taken in non-matching-substring from description and note to text and data.

EDIT 2: Here's an example of how I was thinking of doing this @DanielHaley. As said in my previous reply to you, I use for-each through my larger document (which I haven't posted the entirety of because it's quite long and it would be redundant to the question) to cycle through events and other elements that are under a common parent element.

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="event">
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains(description,'Special')">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="note" regex="\[([^\]]+)\]:\s*([^\[]*)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
       <title><text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))"/></text></title>
       <data><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))"/></data>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <title><text><xsl:value-of select="description"></text></title>
    <data><xsl:value-of select="note"></data>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [xsl:analyze-string](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAA/3)...

**XML Input** (a little mangled for testing regex)

```
<doc>
    <event>
        <description>Special Notice - 20190305</description>
        <note>[Subject]: This is the subject of the event
            [Purpose]: This is the purpose 
            of the event [Evaluation]: This is an evaluation of the event
            [Strategy]:
            This is the strategy for the event</note>
    </event>
    <event>
        <description>Notice</description>
        <note>This is a notice</note>
    </event>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="event[matches(note,'\[[^\]]+\]')]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="note" regex="\[([^\]]+)\]:\s*([^\[]*)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <instance>
          <title>
            <text>
              <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(1))"/>
            </text>
          </title>
          <data>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))"/>
          </data>
        </instance>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <!--This shouldn't trigger. If it does, you'll need to figure out
        how you want to handle the differences with the existing pattern.-->
        <xsl:message terminate="yes" 
          select="concat('Non-matching substring: ''',.,'''')"/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="event">
    <instance>
      <title>
        <text>
          <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </text>
      </title>
      <data>
        <xsl:value-of select="note"/>
      </data>
    </instance>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <instance>
      <title>
         <text>Subject</text>
      </title>
      <data>This is the subject of the event</data>
   </instance>
   <instance>
      <title>
         <text>Purpose</text>
      </title>
      <data>This is the purpose of the event</data>
   </instance>
   <instance>
      <title>
         <text>Evaluation</text>
      </title>
      <data>This is an evaluation of the event</data>
   </instance>
   <instance>
      <title>
         <text>Strategy</text>
      </title>
      <data>This is the strategy for the event</data>
   </instance>
   <instance>
      <title>
         <text>Notice</text>
      </title>
      <data>This is a notice</data>
   </instance>
</doc>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAA

Comment: With XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 and later or AltovaXML 2017 R3 and later) you can even write it a bit more compact using the `analyze-string` function: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAA/2

Comment: I failed to mention that for my non-matching-substring I'm going to want it to grab the description element as the title element and the whole note section as the data element.

So I guess for that section I would just add the title and data elements under non-matching-substring and process with value-of for description and note, respectively?

Comment: @v2kv - can you please update your question with an example of what you’re describing? (Before and after.)

Comment: Just added more detail. Thank you!

Comment: @v2kv - The existing template only matches "note" so the "xsl:non-matching-substring" would only handle "data". What I would do is match the "event" level and have two different templates; one that handles the special "note" elements and one that doesn't. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DanielHaley Mine is a bit different, as my whole XSLT file is too large to post/would detract from the question, but I'm cycling through my parent elements using for-each for each section rather than template match. At the beginning of my XSLT doc I match to the root element. I'll update my post with that I was thinking and if you could give your feedback, I'd really appreciate it.

Also, would you mind including the previous version of the XSLT portion in the comments for comparison?

Comment: @Daniel Haley A version of what I updated with worked for me. I noticed in the documentation for the analyze-string function that non-matching-substring is not mandatory, so I just used my method to grab the non-matching strings.

Thanks very much for your help.  I wasn't aware of this function!